# Can't get customerId when magento tried to retrieve

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, customer-session, no-such-entity-exception

I found this error in var/log exception

> main.CRITICAL:Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: No
>   such entity with customerId =  in
>   /var/www/html/test.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:45

I though it's the one that made error when customer tried to checkout. I don't know what I must do to fix this, is there a way to fix this?